# How do I get let &showbreak=' ' (two spaces between ticks) to work on modeline?

Tags: vim, modeline

I've tried every which way to sunday to make this work but nothing I do seems to work.

I know I can't use `let` on modeline. This is what I'm currently using without `showbreak` in my modeline to wrap the text and indent it.

`/* vim: set breakindent formatoptions=l lbr : */`

And I want to add a showbreak of two spaces in order so that the next word wrapped line lines up with the first character after the bullet point of the prior line.

How can I add the functionality of `let &showbreak='  '` to my modeline? Basically showbreak=.. but replace the periods with spaces?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems that just typing my question answered it ;)

```
/* vim: set breakindent formatoptions=l lbr showbreak=\ \ : */
```

Escapes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).